# After Deleting Parent Object in Master-Detail relation, what happens to the triggers we have created in child object

Tags: trigger, master-detail, delete, childrelationship, parent

In a master detail relationship in child object if we created trigger on child object after delete.when parent is deleted will the trigger execute?

Answer (score 2):

No, records deleted due to cascade deletion will not execute their triggers. Instead, you will need to do that logic in the parent trigger, either by manually deleting the records, or calling the logic from the parent record (requires a trigger framework that uses a class).